# E-mail com cópia JavaMail

Tags: java, primefaces, email, ejb, javamail

Tenho um sistema que envia e-mail, funciona normalmente, quero inserir um campo para enviar copia do e-mail, um CC ou CCo. segue abaixo um trecho do meu código.

Entidade

```
    private String destino;
private String titulo;
private String mensagem;
```

Método enviaEmail

```
 public static void enviaEmail(Ordens ordens) throws EmailException {
     Email email = new SimpleEmail();
     email = conectaEmail();
     email.setSubject(ordens.getTitulo());
     email.setMsg(ordens.getMensagem());
     email.addTo(ordens.getDestino());
     String resposta = email.send();
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "E-mail enviado com sucesso para: " + ordens.getUsuario().getLogin(), "Informação"));
 }
```

Front

```
 <p:panel header="Envio de e-mail">
 <h:panelGrid columns="2">
 <h:outputText value="Para: "/>
 <h:inputText value="#{ordensControle.ordens.destino}" size="48"/>
 <h:outputText value="Título: "/>
 <h:inputText value="#{ordensControle.ordens.titulo}" size="48"/>
 <h:outputText value="Mensagem: "/>
 <h:inputTextarea value="#{ordensControle.ordens.mensagem}" cols="88" 
 rows="10"/>
 </h:panelGrid>
 <p:commandButton value="Enviar e-mail" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed"  
 onclick="PF('statusDialog').show();" action="#
 {ordensControle.enviaEmail()}" update="outputPanelMail"/>
 </p:panel>
```

Biblioteca Ultilizada , commons-email

Comment: Coloque em sua pergunta a biblioteca de email que você utilizou, acredito que seja a apache commons email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método addBcc() para copia oculta e addcc() para copia segue a referencia abaixo.

BCC: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#addBcc(java.lang.String)

CC: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#addCc(java.lang.String)

No seu código poderia ficar da seguinte maneira para CC.

Entidade

```
private String destino;
private String titulo;
private String mensagem;
private List<String> cc;
```

Método enviaEmail

```
public static void enviaEmail(Ordens ordens) throws EmailException {
     Email email = new SimpleEmail();
     email = conectaEmail();
     email.setSubject(ordens.getTitulo());
     email.setMsg(ordens.getMensagem());
     email.addTo(ordens.getDestino());
     for(String cc : ordens.getCc()){
         email.addCc(cc);
     }
     String resposta = email.send();
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "E-mail enviado com sucesso para: " + ordens.getUsuario().getLogin(), "Informação"));
 }
```

Comment: Cara ótimo, vou editar a pergunta pra ver se vc pode me ajudar no Front-End como vai ficar dai.